# postgresql - Sum of columns and group by hour of datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the data stored in the below format :

```
         readiops   |        timestamp 
          3.21          2017-05-26 04:01:00
          5.00          2017-05-26 04:41:00 
          2.12          2017-05-26 03:41:00
          3.00          2017-05-26 03:10:00
          4.00          2017-05-26 03:22:00
          2.33          2017-05-26 02:22:00
          4.21          2017-05-26 02:27:00 
          4.21          2017-05-26 02:27:00
```

I want to get a segregated data i.e the sum of readiops for a given date per hour .

So from the above records i want the below result :

```
          hour_of_day             |       sum_readiops 
           4                              8.21 
           3                              9.12
           2                              10.75
```

Below is my query in postgresql :

```
select sum(cast (readiops as float )) as sum_readiops, 
       extract(hour from date_time) as hour_of_day
from table
where date(date_time) = '2017-05-26'
group by extract(hour from date_time)
```

The output i am getting is really absurd and the counts do not match. Someone please help as i am not sure whats going wrong in my query.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid your trouble,go to below provided solution

```
select  extract(hour from event_time) as hour_of_day ,
        sum(cast (event_data as numeric))

from temp
    group by extract(hour from event_time) 
    order by hour_of_day desc
```

Answer (score 1):

use following query:

```
   select format(sum(readiops),2) as sum_readiops,
   extract(hour from timestamp) as hour_of_day
   from table
   where date(timestamp) = '2017-05-26'
   group by extract(hour from timestamp);
```

Comment: it will not resolve the trouble,your solution will throw type cast error

Comment: why you want to cast? readiops should have float datatype right?

Comment: if you will not cast then 9.12  value will be like this 9.120000000000001 and your have fixed the value that is not required and not a good approach ......... where date(timestamp) = '2017-05-26'

Comment: what is type of readiops as cast only convert from one type to another not limiting decimal points.